# Audio won't keep playing in background

Tags: ios, avplayer, appdelegate

In my app, I have a player:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
```

I want to keep the audio playing when my app is in background. To do that I have :

In MYAPP-Info.plist

[image]

In my AppDelegate .h :

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

In my AppDelegate .m :

```
    // Set AudioSession
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&sessionError];

    /* Pick any one of them */
    // 1. Overriding the output audio route
    // UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    // AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);

    // 2. Changing the default output audio route
   UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
   AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

Unfortunately, the audio won't keep playing in background. Any ideas ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is `player` gets deallocated when current view controller is moved away and get deallocated. Try to keep the player reference by passing the object to next view controller.

Comment: Let's try add those code in applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: When you say it won't keep playing, do you mean as soon as you switch to background, or when the current song finishes? Also, i  take it you are testing on the device and not on the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding..

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
```

After your code..

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
```

Also I see you've already made changes to turn ON audio and airplay in your background modes but have you set Application does not run in background to NO?

[image]